# ruby on rails setup issue on production with docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, puma

### docker file

> 

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/quickcard
ENV BUNDLE_VERSION 2.1.4
ENV BUNDLE_PATH usr/local/bundle/gems
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENV RAILS_PORT 5000
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential \
git \
libxml2-dev \
libpq-dev \
libxslt-dev \
nodejs \
yarn \
imagemagick \
tzdata \
less \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLE_VERSION"
RUN bundle config set path $BUNDLE_PATH
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE $RAILS_PORT
RUN ln -s $RAILS_ROOT/config/systemd/puma.service /etc/systemd/system/current
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

### docker compose file

> 

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: ['bundle','exec','rails','s','-p','5000','-e','production', '-b', '0.0.0.0']
    volumes:
      - /var/wwww/quickcard
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  sidekiq:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
    volumes:
      - '/var/wwww/quickcard/tmp' 
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - app
```

### nginx conf file

> 

```
upstream app {
   server app:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name quickcard;

    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

    location / {
        root /var/www/quickcard/public;
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/quickcard/public/;
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
          root /var/www/quickcard/public/;
          gzip_static on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

1. I want everything on production with docker there are not a single puma configuration or service file on production then how to check puma status if puma start or not?
2. if i am hit ip of server then there is an error site can't be reached. how to configure nginx with application and with puma on production with docker-file. i don't want to set everything manually like puma service file

Comment: Puma should be the main container process, so if the container is running, Puma is too.  On the Nginx error, what's the actual error, what URL are you trying to contact, and do you see the request appear in the Rails logs?

Comment: Logs show me the puma is running as like as shown on the local machine but site not access by the ip and with server name but not a signle request appear on rails logs

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to?  Is anything in the Nginx container logs?  The `links:` option is obsolete and activates an archaic Docker networking mode; does deleting it make any difference (leave it deleted, even if it doesn't help)?

Comment: its work on local with local server ip but when i trying it on production then nginx not access the site i think its due to the redirect from http to https without ssl how to handle it